# Some polygons are loading incorrectly as terra SpatVect but not SpatialPolygonsDataFrames

Tags: raster, r, polygon, terra

I am seeing an issue with some polygon features loading incorrectly as terra SpatVectors. I cannot replicate this issue yet, but
[here is an example polygon as an rds on Google Drive.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XKlEdTAqS3RQuCJrEuGLsFtbptKibRho/view?usp=sharing)

If I load this .rds through readRDS, I have a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame which shows the complete, correct polygon.

However, if I then convert this SpatialPolygonsDataFrame to a SpatVect through: terra::vect(spdf), the polygon has now changed. It is only a single part of the polygon, which is a standalone square part of the polygon. The extent has also changed. I'm not seeing any arguments that could alter this in the documentation for terra::vect.

If I load the original data directly as a SpatVect I have the same issue with this polygon and others. How can I load these polygons as SpatVectors (or convert from SpatialPolygonsDataFrame if necessary), but have the polygon shape remain correct?

Comment: Your rds appears to be corrupt but, nonetheless I would recommend converting to an sf object using `sf::st_as_sf(spdf)`. This will hopefully retain multipart geometry. I honestly do not see a compelling reason to coerce to a SpatVect object as sf is much more powerful. There are a few instances where the result is a SpatVect (eg., vectorization using `terra::as.polygons`) object but, the power in vector analysis lays in the sf package. If you are want to use `terra::extract` or `exactextractr::exact_extract` sf vector objects are directly supported. You can always coerce sf to SpatVect.

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue with your polygons. In short, they are invalid.

```r
a <- readRDS("/home/sapi/Downloads/test_polygon.rds")

sp::plot(a)
```

[image]

So far so good. But in {terra}, as you said, only first polygon is plotted:

```r
a |>
  terra::vect() |>
  terra::plot()
```

[image]

Let's check it's (in)validity:

```r
a |>
  terra::vect() |>
  terra::is.valid()
#> [1] FALSE
```

and repair it:

```r
a |>
  terra::vect() |>
  terra::makeValid() |>
  terra::plot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-02-06 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The similar approach can be used in {sf}: `sf::st_as_sf() |> sf::st_make_valid()`.

Comment: Thank you, I thought there was a function like that I was trying to remember.

Short of checking for issues like this / knowing when it may be an issue, is there any way you know of the expect that it will be necessary to use makeValid()?

Comment: Not by definition. Sometimes a warning message can be thrown by function, sometimes the results are far away from what is expected. But to generalize - it can be assumed that files downloaded from the Internet, prepared by someone in an unknown way, may be defective. Moreover, `rds` is a non-spatial data format, my experience with sf features tells me that storing spatial data in such files is asking for trouble.